# Does GCP have an API call to check resource availability?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-api-python-client

We keep getting `ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED` when we try to deploy VMs in the zones of the `us-central1` region. Apparently, GCP doesn't have enough VMs to fill the request.

We tried other regions one by one `us-east1`, `us-east4`, etc. all returned the same error until finally found that `us-east5` have VMs available and we're now temporarily using it.

Is there an API call to check GCP resource availability so we can directly deploy VMs in that zone?

For example,

```
# call
r = get_resources(machine_type, zone)
# returns:
[{
  'service': 'compute_engine',
  'machine_type': '2-standard4',
  'available': True
  'stock': 4560
}, ...
]
```

**Note**

1. Machine type we're using `e2-custom-2-4096` (Custom E2 family machine).
2. The desired API call would check **if GCP itself has resources in that zone or region**, not the project quota!

Answer (score 1):

No such dashboards, API method (or) Feature to give the resource availability in GCP.

But while creating resources if you face any issues like `ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED`, please follow the guidelines mentioned in the official document for
[Troubleshooting errors that you might encounter while creating or updating VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability)